# Flutter: MissingPluginException when I call platform channel from spawned isolate using isolate_handler package

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, flutter-method-channel

When I want to call a method channel from a spawned isolate using isolate_handler (because it doesn't work using dart's isolates), I get a MissingPluginException which doesn't happen when calling method channel from the main isolate.

```
 class TestingIsolate {
  static int _callCount = 0;
  static int _lastNumber = 0;

  final _isolates = IsolateHandler();

  final resultStreamController = StreamController<double>();

  static void _entryPoint(Map<String, dynamic> context) {
    final messenger = HandledIsolate.initialize(context);

    _startTesting(messenger);
  }

  Stream<double> init() {
    _isolates.spawn<double>(_entryPoint,
        onReceive: (result) => resultStreamController.add(result));

    return resultStreamController.stream;
  }

  static const platform =
      MethodChannel('com.mycompany.plugin_performance_test_poc');

  static void _startTesting(HandledIsolateMessenger messenger) {
    // Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    //   messenger.send(_callCount / timer.tick);
    // });

    final stopwatch = Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.start();
    while (stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds < 3000) {
      platform.invokeMethod('performanceTest', {'data': _lastNumber}).then(
          (result) {
            print("inside, $_lastNumber");
        _lastNumber = result;
        _callCount++;
      });
    }
    stopwatch.stop();

    messenger.send(_callCount * 3000 / stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
  }

}
```

I'm trying to test how many times can I run method channel per second.

Here's the UI part:

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_performance_test_poc/testing_isolate.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _counter = 0;

  Future<void> _executeTest() async {
    TestingIsolate().init().listen((result) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = result;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'The plugin has been called this many times per second:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _executeTest,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

And A native part of the code for android:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.mycompany.plugin_performance_test_poc"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            if (call.method == "performanceTest") {
                if (call.hasArgument("data")) {
                    result.success(call.argument<Int>("data") as Int + 1)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```